# Python using import in a function, import content of variable and not its name?

Tags: python, function, import

I have a function that checks if a module is installed, if not it will install it. I am passing the extension through a function. However how can I stop it attempting to import the variable name and use its contents?

Example:

```
def importExtension(extension):
     try:
        import extension
    except:
        Do stuff
importExtension("blah")
```

Comment: If I correctly understand your problem you can add `del extension` after `import`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [importlib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) ([backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/importlib/)).

```
import importlib

def importExtension(extension):
     try:
        importlib.import_module(name)
    except:
        Do stuff
importExtension("blah")
```

---

Also, to quote the docs about `__import__(..)`:

> This is an advanced function that is not needed in everyday Python programming, unlike importlib.import_module().